# RaphaelJS: How to animate element after another elements animation is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, raphael

I want to animate a element after previous element has finished its animation. Righ now my code is like this:

```
var canvas = Raphael(0, 0, 1000, 1000 );
    var boxWidth = 80;
    var boxHeight = 30;
    var rectangles = canvas.set();
    rectangles.push(canvas.rect(460, 30, 0, 0),
                    canvas.rect(460, 90, 0, 0),
                    canvas.rect(460, 150, 0, 0),
                    canvas.rect(460, 210, 0, 0),
                    canvas.rect(460, 270, 0, 0));
    rectangles.attr({fill: "#e00", stroke: "#fff"});

    rectangles[0].animate(anim.delay(200));
    rectangles[1].animate(anim.delay(400));
    rectangles[2].animate(anim.delay(800));
    rectangles[3].animate(anim.delay(1200));
    rectangles[4].animate(anim.delay(1600));
```

Here I have manually provided incremented delay values like 200,400,800. For a large set of elements, this will be pretty tiresome calculation. I think there must be another way to do this by linking one animation to other animations end. Please Guide.

Comment: One option is to use jquery when and then option. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something missing from your code posted above. And that missing bit is exactly how you'd run another animation once an animation is complete.

The missing bit is how you created your `anim` object.

When creating `anim`, [`Raphael.animation`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.animation) allows you to supply a callback that will be called once an animation is complete:

```
var anim = Raphael.animation(params, duration, easing, next_callback);

function next_calback () {/* ... */}
```

Now you can process your rectangles like this:

```
var i=0;
function next_callback () {
    if (rectangles[i]) {
        rectangles[i].animate(anim);
        i++;
    }
}

next_callback(); // kickstart the animation
```

Of course, you can name your callback something more descriptive than `next_callback` and you can wrap the whole thing in a closure so that `i` isn't exposed as a global variable but that's the basic structure.

Answer (score 0):

use rectangles code in loop.  add animation code in loop . here delay increase automatically to 200,400,800,1600

```
var delay = 200;
for(i = 0;i<rectangles.length;i++){
  rectangles[i].animate(anim.delay(delay));
  delay = delay+delay;
}
```